# Cube roots of the complex numbers 1+i?

Tags: complex-numbers

I cant get any good reference in my books regarding cube of complex numbers. Please help me find cube roots of the Complex number i+1??

Comment: You could use the polar form of $1+i$.

Comment: $ {(re^{i \theta }}) ^\frac13= { r ^\frac13 e^{i \theta/3 }} $

Answer (score 6):

The way for finding the nth roots of a complex number, is to express it in the form of $r.cis(\theta)$.  The function $cis()=cos()+i.sin()$.

For example, if one has $x+iy$, one can find $\theta=arctan(y/x)$, with appropriate quadrant adjustment, and $r^2=x^2+y^2$.

The value of the nth roots, are then $r^{1/n} cis(2\pi*m/n+\theta/n)$, for $m = 0, \ldots, n-1$.

In your case 1+i gives $r=\sqrt{2}$, and $\theta=45°$.

The angles of the cube root are at $15°$, $135°$, and $255°$, with a radius of $2^{1/6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you let $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, then every complex number can be uniquely represented by $re^{i\theta}$. Now the cube roots are just this number raised to the $1/3$ power.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1+i = \sqrt{2} e^{i\pi/4}$, we have

$$(1+i)^{1/3} = 2^{1/6} e^{i\pi/12}.$$

Alternatively, $1+i$ could be written $\sqrt{2} e^{9i\pi/4}$ or $\sqrt{2} e^{17i\pi/4}$, providing two more cube roots.  WolframAlpha provides a [nice illustration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cube%20roots%20of%20%281%2bi%29) of this:

[image]

Comment: Except when you don't have access to WolframAlpha in an exam :-(

Comment: @peter The picture is pretty easy to come up with on your own, if you understand the polar form of complex numbers. You have the principle root, closest to the real axis, and the others are evenly spread out over the unit circle. I used to WolframAlpha just to produce the image for posting here. I used WolframAlpha because I happened to work for Wolfram Research at the time.